# How can I remove the transform typeof symbol code from my Babel compiled code?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I recently added babel to my gulpfile so I can start writing code in ES6. The code is compiling as expected, but I noticed the following line of code gets added, in multiple places, to the compiled JS file. I don't think I will need it, and therefore would like to remove it:

`var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };`

**What I've tried**:

In `gulpfile.babel.js`, inside `createBuildTask()`, I set `presets` like so: `'presets': [['env', {'exclude': ['transform-typeof-symbol']}]]`

...which resulted in the following error getting returned during the gulp build:

`Invalid Option: The plugins/built-ins 'transform-typeof-symbol' passed to the 'exclude' option are not valid. Please check data/[plugin-features|built-in-features].js in babel-preset-env`

Is this the correct approach for removing, or should I be handling it differently? Below I've included the relevant parts of my `package.json`, as well as `gulpfile.babel.js`.

**package.json** (including *dev*, *devDependencies*)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-terser": "^1.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-strict-mode": "0.0.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
}
```

**gulpfile.babel.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var terser = require('gulp-terser');

function createBuildTask() {
    var sourceArray = [
        'common/*.js',
        'nep/api/*.js',
        'nep/controller/*.js',
        'nep/legacy/*.js',
        'nep/nep-sat.js'
    ];

    return function () {
        return gulp.src(sourceArray, {'allowEmpty': true})
            .pipe(babel({
                'presets': ['env'],
                'plugins': ['transform-remove-strict-mode']
            }))
            .pipe(concat('nep-built-sat.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('nep/dist'))
            .pipe(terser())
            .pipe(rename({
                'extname': '.min.js'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('nep/dist'));
    };
}

function createLintTask(destination) {
    return function () {
        return gulp.src(destination + '/' + destination + '-sat.js')
            .pipe(eslint())
            .pipe(eslint.format())
            .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
    };
}

gulp.task('lint-nep', createLintTask('nep'));
gulp.task('build-nep', createBuildTask());

gulp.task('nep', gulp.series('lint-nep', 'build-nep'));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('lint-nep', 'build-nep'));

gulp.task('clean', (done) => {
    del.sync(['*/dist']);
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Turns out you have to pass full package names when excluding (found by trial and error):

```
--- a/babel.config.json
+++ b/babel.config.json
@@ -1,15 +1,18 @@
 {
   "plugins": [
     "@babel/plugin-transform-strict-mode",
     "add-module-exports"
   ],
   "presets": [
     [
       "@babel/env",
       {
         "bugfixes": true,
+        "exclude": [
+          "@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol"
+        ],
         "modules": "auto"
       }
     ]
   ]
 }
```